# when i run my code in pycharm it is working fine but when i try to run the same code from server i am getting error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pynput

hi i am new to selenium automation .

The code which i have written is working fine and executing in both pycharm and command prompt but when i try to execute the same code from remote server i am getting the below error .

I understand it as do something with pynput but i am not able to figure out how to solve it .
If anyone know about it please help me out .

```
 File "/home/manoj/forum-test-suite/test_forum_page/PageObject/common_methods.py", line 6, in <module>
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from . import keyboard
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from ._xorg import KeyCode, Key, Controller, Listener
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 39, in <module>
from pynput._util.xorg import (
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 40, in <module>
_check()
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pynput/_util/xorg.py", line 38, in _check
display = Xlib.display.Display()
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
File "/home/manoj/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 167, in __init__
raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
```

Comment: It is saying `Client is not authorized to connect to Server` make sure you have successful connection

Comment: Hi @NarendraR  that one i corrected it leaving that one line rest of the error  is same , sorry for not changing it

Comment: How does your actual driver initialization look like? Also, how is the environment? The error is complaining about X server connection problem - do you have an window manager system on the machine where the browser should be executed?

Comment: I was able to resolve it, the issue was with respect to the path variable @skandigraun

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with respect to the pynput , you need to go to your .bashprofile and append
the pynput path , in PYTHONPATH that you have set .By doing this i was able to solve this issue.